# Convert multiple data types to NSData objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, byte, nsdata, type-conversion

How can I convert `long long` (8 bytes), `int` (4 bytes), `short` (2 bytes), `Byte` (1 byte) and `NSString` to an array bytes (NSData) to send it over the Internet ?

ie, how can I convert these into bytes:

`long long currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];`

`int databaseVersion = [SqliteUtils getDatabaseVersion];`

`Byte type = 2`

etc ...

Thanks.

Comment: How you want to send them ? GameKit, TCP connection, websocket, JSON, HTTP ? Is it between two iOS devices or between iOS and server side ?

Comment: Thank for asking Grzegorz, I want to them via Http POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For primitive types:

```
int a = 10;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&a length:sizeof(a)];
```

For `NSString`:

```
NSData *data = [@"string" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: one more think, how can I encrypt this `data` using bitwise `XOR` with another `NSData` as key ? I don't know how to enumerate through these data. `enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:` doesn't work, maybe I've done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[NSData dataWithBytes:&currentTime length:sizeof(currentTime)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and NSKeyUnarchiver. The concept is called data serialization or marshalling. Basically it allows you to serialize an arbitary Objective-C object to get an NSData object